# Minimize animation in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.04, animations

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 18.04. I installed Tweaks and have been fiddling around, but I've noticed a missing option. In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I had an option enabled that changed the animation of minimizing a window to make it seem similar to Mac's minimize animation:

[image]

In Ubuntu 18.04, it seems that this animation might be missing? I'm wondering if there's a viable replacement. I looked around and couldn't find much, so I'm turning to this community for help.

Answer (score 3):

It is not missing.

Since 17.10 release, Ubuntu changed its Desktop Environment from Unity to Gnome-Shell. Unity use Compiz as its compositing manager. Compiz provide that animation. IIRC, the animation is called magic lamp. On the other hand Gnome-Shell use Mutter as its compositing manager and magic lamp is never available in Gnome-Shell/Mutter.

If you still really want the magic lamp animation, KDE compositing manager KWIN have one! Also I've seen people use Compiz on XFCE. So your option is either Kubuntu install or Xubuntu install. Though it will be a lot easier if you choose Kubuntu since KWIN is the default while XFCE default is XFWM and Compiz is not really well maintained anymore.